# JQuery $(selector).each() with two divs

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$("#sortable").children('ul li').each(function(index, item) {

    $("#house_wall1").children('.item' + index).attr('alt', index);
});
```

This code is a part of two divs, `#sortable` and `#house_wall1`.

It has to change the `alt` value to the index of `#sortable` but right now, it just changes the `alt` value for the `#house_wall1` index. Is there a way to change line 3 to something like this: (Psedo code):

```
$("#house_wall1").children('.item' + index).attr('alt', index AT #sortable);
```

If this is not possible, it would be fine to do something like this:

```
var i = 0;

$("#sortable").children('ul li').each(function(index, item) {

    $("#house_wall1").children('.item' + index).attr('alt', i);
i++;
});
```

But this doesn't work either for some reason. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Better explanation:

I have two divs with two different indexes. When this line is run:

```
$("#house_wall1").children('.item' + index).attr('alt', index);
```

the index of `#house_wall1` is set as the `alt` attribute, instead of the index of `#sortable`. So the alt value is just set equal to a wrong index.

Uhmm.. I don't know if that was any easier to understand, it's such a weird problem.

Usefull additional information:

The first div `#sortable` looks for an index of `#ul li`
The last div `#house_wall1` should look for an index of `img` attribute

HTML:

For `#sortable`

```
echo '<li id="item-' . $arr['number'] . '" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' . $arr['name'] . ' 
<img class="rotate" id="img_'.$arr['number'].'" src="images/house/other/settings.jpg" onclick="rotateObject(this,\''. $arr['src']. '\')">';
```

For `#house_wall1`

```
echo '<img src="' . $src . $rotation .'.png" class="item' . $item_number . '" 
rel="'.$rotation.'" alt="'.$z.'" style="position:absolute; left:' . $x . 'px; top:' . $y . 
'px; z-index:'. $z . ';">'; if ($x != 0) { echo'</a>'; }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand *"It has to change the alt value to the index of #sortable but right now, it just changes the alt value for the #house_wall1 index."*. Could you try to better explain your problem? An actually example of the result/output would be helpful as well.

Comment: no idea what is being asked here

Comment: @FelixKling Kling I have added another explanation.. Not sure it helps though, because it says the exact same with different words in my head. I could create an example, but it'll just take some minutes then :)

Comment: `index` refers to the value passed to the `.each` callback, which is the index of the `#sortable ul li` element. I highly doubt it refers to `#house_wall1` in any way.

Comment: @FelixKling That is exactly what I expected it to do as well, and hence I was so confused. Well, I really don't know what could be the issue, since the `alt` attribute doesn't get equal to the index of `#sortable`.

Comment: Yoyu're trying to set to "#house_wall1" the index of the "#sortable"? right now the index variable points the index of an li

Comment: Well, there really isn't much else we can say about it without the HTML or a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: @EduardoQuintana yeah that might be the problem, since it should look for an index of images in the `#house_wall1`. hmm

Comment: This is an example with some test html it changes the alt attribute of the childrens in house_wall1 http://jsfiddle.net/Mh4aL/ but if you can provide us your html it will be easier

Comment: I have added some extra information to the question, that explains the problem A LOT better. Thanks for this information @EduardoQuintana. This has to be the problem.

Comment: @EduardoQuintana I added the HTML, I guess that's enough for what you need, the two divs #sortable and #house_wall1 is correct, so don't worry about them thanks

Comment: Try to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) as @FelixKling proposed it will better than the server side code

Comment: Umh yeah, but @EduardoQuintana, your jsFiddle example is the exact same as my code, except for the fact that #house_wall1 contains `img` instead of `p`'s. That's the only difference really

Comment: @owwyess: Are you also using `find` instead of `children`?

Comment: @owwyess And the fiddle works for you http://jsfiddle.net/Mh4aL/1/ this is another version with img inside of it and it sets the alt to the image with the same index of the sortable div

Comment: ahh it's weird because it's exactly what I need @EduardoQuintana and yes I did Felix, thanks for reminding.
Do I have the specify the `"div"` to something or let it be as it is?

Comment: If you have multiple divs then select them on the each but if it's only that sortable div it will work since it's looking for the closest div div#sortable > ul > li the each loops on the li elements so the closest div element on the parent's tree is the div#sortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this HTML (assuming it's similar to the one generated )

```
<div id="sortable">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div id="house_wall1">
    <img class="item1" src="something.png"/>
    <img class="item2" src="something.png"/>
</div>
```

Code

```
$("#sortable").find("ul li").each(function(index, item) {
    //Get the index of the closest div to the li , in this case is div#sortable
    var indexSortable = $(this).closest("div").index() + 1 //the index of sortable is 0 we a dd 1 to match with the item[number] class on the images.
    $("#house_wall1").children('.item' + indexSortable).attr('alt', indexSortable);
});
```

Please let me know if this fixs your problem.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mh4aL/1/)

**If sortable is the ul:**

```
$("#sortable").children("li").each(function(index, item) {
    //Get the index of the parent in this case the ul sortable
    var indexSortable = $(this).parent().index() + 1 
    $("#house_wall1").children('.item' + indexSortable).attr('alt', indexSortable);
});
```

**Solution**

```
$("#sortable").find("li img").each(function(){
  //The images hold an id like image_1 and the img in house_wall1 a class like item1
  //This is the relationship between them so we get the id and remove the "img_" part
  //of the id to get the number and assign the attr to the item[n] class on house_wall

var actualItem = $(this).attr("id").replace("img_","item")
var index = $(this).parent().index()

$("#house_wall1").find("img."+actualItem).attr("alt",index)

})
```

Comment: How would it work if `<div id="sortable">` was changed to `<ul id="sortable">` just for trying? Still having trouble but I have many things to try, it will work eventually!

Comment: Well what happens is that the `alt` value doesn't get changed at all, it remains the same. Well I have all this online, if we could start a chat somehow, I could just link it to you quickly maybe? Uhmm else I don't know what to try next

Comment: In the fiddle the only img that get's the alt attribute changed is the first since we are getting the index of the sortable which is the same in this case 0 (+1 that we add) the next li on the loop it's the same the index of the parent ul or div is the same if we change this for example to point to the li index all the alt attr on the images with .item[n] will be changed. In this http://jsfiddle.net/Mh4aL/2/ you could look that the alt is changed getting the index of the li's  first iteration (li index 0) search in house_wall1 a children with class .item[0 + 1]

Comment: ohh.. Uhm that is almost what I need, but not exactly. Umm it would be really easy for you to see if I could just write you a PM, I don't want to share the information here. Uhm

Comment: Hm since i'm behind a proxy it's doesn't leave to open the chats you can use my email(profile) if you like

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in selector within [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method.
Problem is that [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) only travels a single level down the DOM, but you asking for second level element ul > li.

Solution is to use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/#find-selector) method :

```
$("#sortable").find('ul li').each(function(index, item){
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Good point, but whether it really is the problem or not can only be known after looking at the HTML.

Comment: code "$("#sortable").children('ul li')" tell us that user trying to find <li /> that inside <ul /> in <x id="sortable" /> element.

Comment: Well... it could also be that `#sortable` is the `ul` element, and then `.children('ul li')` would work fine. Granted, the selector would be a bit confusing, but it would work. That's why I'm saying this *could* be the problem, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: if #sortable is <ul />, then there are no any logical reason to use 'ul li' as a children. (:

Comment: I'm not saying there is. I'm saying that if `#sortable` is a `ul` element, then `$("#sortable").children('ul li')` works as expected. So, your solution is based on the assumption that `#sortable` is *not* a `ul` element. And I'm just saying that this can only be verified by looking at the HTML. Nothing more, nothing less.